# A condition gets checked twice (or more) after completion of a function. Godot 4.0.2

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

```
if CustomObject.string_parameter == ButtonReference.text:
    set_process(false)
    my_function(Node, CustomObject)
```

The `my_function` above does a bunch of stuff, but what is important it `queue_free`'s the button I reference in the condition check. So, logically, when executing the code, it should go like this:

1. If `bool` from `String` check is `true`
2. Set process to `false`
3. Do stuff
4. Return/Stop

However, in some cases it would go for a second check AFTER already executing `my_function` (during the first check) which "destroys" the checked `button`. And then it just throws an error that it is a Nil object with no `text` property. But it happens only in specific cases. I checked that no signals interfere with the "destruction" of the button. So, the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to put `break` at the end, so that the code is explicitly forced to exit the iteration. Now it works as intended 100%.